# Tool preferences for rapidly spinning up and spinning down k8s clusters

Tags: ansible, kubernetes, chef, testing, puppet

My team hosts several completely different projects on a production k8s cluster with a given configuration. We use AWS (and are starting to use Google Cloud). We have a QA cluster as well, that "sort of" mimics the production configuration, and has a few test projects deployed on it as well. I say "sort of" because right now we just have a collection of shell scripts and custom commands that an engineer manually ran to create the clusters. This had a bad consequence when we made a change to the configuration on the QA and production cluster, and it prevented deployment to that cluster until we reverted the change.

I am looking to implement Infrastructure as Code (IAC) and a corresponding CI/CD pipeline to prevent this. The goal is that a PR will trigger a build that will spin up a cluster by following the IAC steps, deploy some projects on it, run some tests, then spin down the cluster and provide a test report.

I am investigating Kops, Ansible, Chef, and Puppet as candidates for this task. Right now the shell scripts I mentioned before are mostly kops commands. I have been spending the last few days reading about the other three technologies as well, and I am not quite sure how they might fit into what I need.

Are there any recommendations for my particular use case? Implement IAC and a CI/CD pipeline that can spin up a new k8s cluster with the proposed changes and then spin it down once tests finish?

Comment: I'd go with a templating system (chef for my part, but any would do) to create those kops scripts... I'm afraid there's no silver bullet there and that everyone will have its favorite method based on the tooling they're used to

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

https://github.com/heptio/aws-quickstart

Their CTO uses it to spin up K8S clusters for his weekly youtube live stream called TGIK, in order to showcase whatever he wants to talk about.

I myself use GKE so I do not need it.